I want to add a header to all the pages in the doc file Im using Export2Doc()
I need help on adding a header on the exported document.
Im using this JS code
When I added a header like this
<style>
.header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
  }
</style>

<div class="exportContent">
       <div class="header">
        <p>Header Content</p>
    </div>
<div class="body">
// Body Content        
    </div>
    </div>

The Header only displays in one page and not in the header section of the document.
enter image description here
I need to display it on the top of the document on every file.

You have a mess in your pagedefinition!
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <style>
    .pageheader {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 1;
      }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="exportContent">
       <div class="pageheader">
           <p>Header Content</p>
      </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>

By the way: do not mix header and pageheader. That is not the same. The header is to define the page. The pageheader is used to display on the page.
